# Differential Calculus problem- does anyone know how to solve this?

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Two circles of radius $r$ are tangent to each other. Two lines pass through the centre of one circle and are tangent to the other circle at points $A$ and $B$ as shown in the diagram. Find an expression for the distance between $A$ and $B$.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

---

I was thinking about setting up a function for the circle and differentiate it to find the tangents at point $A$ and $B$- except I have no idea how to set up the function. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

[1] :https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxLTa.png

Comment: By having accepted a geometry-based solution, are you saying that you are no longer interested in a calculus-based one? If so, then you should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm still looking for a calculus-based solution (as this question was from the calculus topic), so I wasn't sure if I should accept the solution or not, but I've just un-accpeted it. So hopefully someone would come up with a calculus-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calculus-based approach isn't as elegant as the geometry-based ones shown in other answers, but it can be instructive.

We'll take the circles to have centers at $P(-2r,0)$ and $Q(0,0)$, so that the right-hand circle has equation
$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \tag{1}$$
Implicit differentiation gives $2x + 2yy^\prime = 0$, so that the slope of the tangent to that circle at, say, $A(a_x,a_y)$ is
$$m = -\frac{a_x}{a_y} \tag{2}$$
But the tangent line must pass through $P$, so we can calculate the slope of the line using $A$ and $P$:
$$m = \frac{a_y - 0}{a_x-(-2r)} = \frac{a_y}{a_x+2r} \tag{3}$$
Equating $(2)$ and $(3)$, and recalling that $(a_x,a_y)$ satisfies $(1)$, we have
$$-\frac{a_x}{a_y} = \frac{a_y}{a_x+2r} \;\to\; -a_x(a_x+2r) = a_y^2 = r^2- a_x^2 \;\to\; a_x=-\frac12 r \;\to\; a_y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r \tag{4}$$
Since the distance from $A$ to $B$ is clearly twice distance from $A$ to the $x$-axis, we conclude

> $$|\overline{AB}| = 2 a_y = r \sqrt{3} \tag{$\star$}$$

Things are a little messier if you use *explicit* differentiation on 
$$y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
Alternatively, one can differentiate the parametric representation of the circle $$(r \cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$$
In any case, the strategy of comparing the calculus-derived slope to the basic rise-over-run calculation gives the condition that leads to the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ and $D$ be the centers of the left and right circles respectively.  Since $A$ and $B$ are points of tangency, $\angle CAD = \angle CBD = 90°$.  In each of these right-angled triangles, hypotenuse $CD = 2r$ and adjacent side $AD = BD = r$, so opposite side $\angle ADC = \angle BDC = 60°$.

$$AB = 2r \sin\angle BDC = 2r \sin60° = 2r \cdot \frac{\sqrt3}{2} = \sqrt3 r$$

Answer (score 0):

Let C and D be the centers of the circles.

Then look at the triangle A-C-D. It is a rectangular triangle and the lengths of two edges are known.

So you can calculate the distance between A and the center of the left circle.

Then you can calculate the height of the triangle (which is half the distance you are searching for).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, let $L(0,0)$ and $R(2r,0)$ be the centers of the left and right circles. The line through $LA$ has equation:
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x,$$
because its slope is $\tan \measuredangle ALR=\tan 30=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and its y-intercept is $0$ as it passes through the origin.

The line through $AR$ is perpendicular to $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x$ and has the equation:
$$y=-\sqrt{3}x+2\sqrt{3}r.$$
Now the point $A(x,y)$ is at an intersection of the two lines:
$$\begin{cases} y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x \\ y=-\sqrt{3}x+2\sqrt{3}r \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x=\sqrt{3}y \\ y=-\sqrt{3}\cdot (\sqrt{3}y)+2\sqrt{3}r \end{cases} \Rightarrow y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r.$$
Hence:
$$AB=2y=r\sqrt{3}.$$